# Where can I view a map with buildings/businesses that were present sometimes in the past?

Tags: online-resources, maps, history, google-maps

From time to time, businesses (e.g., restaurants) close or buildings are destructed. Where can I view a map with buildings/businesses that were present in a given point in the past? (e.g., "show me map of Seattle in 2010"). I'm trying to recall the name of some place I went to when traveling, which has closed since then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Maps Street View has a timeline.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Land Viewer | EOS](https://eos.com/landviewer/) website you can use. You can choose the area of interest from the map and have a timeline of satellite imageries from the same area.

For example, I looked at Seattle:

[image: Seattle]

Of course it has some cons. For example, it sometimes has a great cloud coverage, which makes it a good tool for meteoroligsts. Also, when zoomed in, the quality of the picture decreases. And also, it's not really free of charge if you want to see more than 10 pictures a day. Yet another con: it's boring to go through dates to reach the desired date. And also, sometimes it doesn't show the name of buildings.

Also, there is [World History Maps & Timelines | GeaCron](http://geacron.com/home-en/) website if you are interested to see the world map with the territories of old kingdoms and empires. Fortunately, this part is free of charge. But if you want to see more than it (i.e. historical military campaigns, etc) you have to pay.

[image: 1500 AD]

Comment: Very cool, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)